# Input type hidden adds a break. How do I remove them?

Tags: html, css

Title says. Pretty sure I can fix it with CSS, I tried `form > br {display: none;}` but didn't work.

```html
<form method='POST' action='../buildapc' enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type='hidden' name='".$mainStore."'/>

    <input type='hidden' name='".$cpuCount."/>
    <input type='hidden' name='".$cpuName."/>
    <input type='hidden' name='".$cpuStore."/>

    <button type='submit' class='alignRight'>← RETURN TO BUILD A PC</button>
</form>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "break"? A line break or a space?

Comment: check first those 3 inputs at the middle `name='".$variable."/>` it must be `name='".$variable."'>`

Comment: Your code is `name='".$cpuCount."` , `name='".$cpuCount."'` or `name=".$cpuCount."`

Comment: @MarkSalvania and Ｈｏｎｇａｒｃ I forgot to mention this was inside a PHP echo. Unsure if that would help or not

Answer (score 1):

You should provide the exact source code to get a proper analysis about your problem. Hidden fields (when no direct css formatting is done towards those fields) normally do not emit any kind of space. If you add an `<br />` after a hidden input, simply remove it, because hidden inputs are not rendered because of their nature.

I found your issue. Your HTML source is malformed. Do use this:

```
<form method='POST' action='../buildapc' enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type='hidden' name='{$mainStore}'/>

    <input type='hidden' name='{$cpuCount}' />
    <input type='hidden' name='{$cpuName}' />
    <input type='hidden' name='{$cpuStore}' />

    <button type='submit' class='alignRight'>← RETURN TO BUILD A PC</button>
</form>
```

But this will only work when the string/concatenation chain was started with a `"`, `'` will not allow to embed variables like this.

Comment: Your provided code does not emit spaces. Check the CSS definitions for the form or any forms. You should also consider to use " instead of ' when defining HTML. It might be only have esthetic origins, but it will be more readable across websites and also have a "theoretically better" performance impact when you do express strings using ' instead of ", because ' do not await embedded entities as " would do from the perspective of PHP. HTML does not really care about the quotation marks. You already do mix both which might be an issue here without knowing the surrounding source code.

Answer (score -1):

In your stylesheet: Add

```
  Input [type="hidden"] 
       {
         visibility: hidden;
        }
```

I hope, it helps you

Comment: This would hide all descendant elements of `Input` elements that have an attribute named `type` with the value `hidden`. `input` cannot have descendant elements, so this selector will **never match any elements** .